# How do I fix this issue where my 2D array won't output it's values in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string A[5][2] = {{"Shane","M"},{"Michael","M"},{"Devika","F"},{"Akshi","F"},{"Zia","F"}};

    for(int i=0; i<5,i++;){
        for (int j=0; j<2;j++){
            //cout<< "Element at A["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]: ";
            cout<<A[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

I was writing that code for a lab in my class and the code won't output the array values. Anyone know how I can fix this and what the problem is?

Comment: you should pay attention to warnings. With gcc use `-Werror -Wall` and your code will fail to compile with a message pointing you right to the typo

Comment: Typo: `for(int i=0; i<5,i++;){ ...` should be `for(int i=0; i<5;i++){ ...`

Comment: Well, the point of learning is learn how to learn. If debugging is something that you won't do well, it would be difficult to learn anything else in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop

```
for(int i=0; i<5,i++;)
```

is wrong. The condition `i<5,i++` means `i++` because the left operand of the *comma operator* `i<5` doesn't have side effect and simply ignored. `i++` is evaluated to the value before the increment. In this case the value is 0, so it is considered as false and the loop body won't executed.

The loop should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Also you should add

```
#include <string>
```

at the top of your code to use the `string` type and add

```
}
```

at the end of your code to finish the definition of the function body.